# ROWID in casted pl-sql collection

Tags: oracle, collections, plsql, rowid

Is there any rowid like facility in a pl-sql collection? In my case, while I am using this collection in an sql query, I also need the sequence number as they are put in. I know modification is data struecture is a way, but I want to use the index of the collection. so what I am looking for is something like this:

```
TYPE t_List IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(200);
```

and

```
declare
v_Data t_List := t_List('data 1'
                       ,'data_2'
                       ,'data3');
......

FOR Rec IN (SELECT Column_Value v
                  ,ROWID        r
            FROM   TABLE(CAST(v_data t_list)))
LOOP
    Dbms_Output.Put_Line('at ' || Rec.r || ':' || Rec.v);
    -- .... and other codes here
END LOOP;
```

The loop is not expected to be executed in sequence, but I want something built-in like ROWID that is like the index of the collection.

Comment: You've made it look like the type is defined in PL/SQL; is it, or is it defined at schema level with `create type`?

Comment: oh.. sorry.. It is schema level type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only schema-level types can be used in SQl statement, even within a PL/SQL block. As you seem to suggest you already know, you can create your own object type that includes the 'sequence' ID:

```
CREATE TYPE t_object AS OBJECT (
  id NUMBER,
  data VARCHAR2(200)
)
/
```

And a collection of that type:

```
CREATE TYPE t_List IS TABLE OF t_object;
/
```

And then populate the ID as you build the list:

```
DECLARE
  l_List t_List := t_List(t_object(1, 'data 1')
                         ,t_object(2, 'data_2')
                         ,t_object(3, 'data3'));
BEGIN
  FOR Rec IN (SELECT id, data
              FROM   TABLE(l_list))
  LOOP
    Dbms_Output.Put_Line('at ' || Rec.id || ':' || Rec.data);
    -- .... and other codes here
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Without an object type you *can* use the `ROWNUM` pseudocolumn:

```
CREATE TYPE t_List IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(200);
/

DECLARE
  v_Data t_List := t_List('data 1'
                         ,'data_2'
                         ,'data3');
BEGIN
  FOR Rec IN (SELECT Column_Value v
                    ,ROWNUM       r
              FROM   TABLE(v_data))
  LOOP
      Dbms_Output.Put_Line('at ' || Rec.r || ':' || Rec.v);
      -- .... and other codes here
  END LOOP;
END;
/

anonymous block completed
at 1:data 1
at 2:data_2
at 3:data3
```

As far as I'm aware that isn't guaranteed to preserve the original creation sequence. I think it almost certainly will at the moment, but perhaps isn't something you should rely on as always being true. ([There is no order without an `order by`](http://tkyte.blogspot.co.uk/2005/08/order-in-court.html), but here you don't have anything you can order by without destroying your initial order...).

If you query a subset of the table - I'm not sure what you mean by "the loop is not expected to be executed in sequence" - you'd need to generate the `ROWNUM` in a subquery before filtering or it won't be consistent. You'd also need to generate the `ROWNUM` in a subquery if you're joining this to other, real, tables - I imagine you are, otherwise you could use a PL/SQL collection.

Comment: I am trying to give you an example. Say, this collection is holding the names of the participants who have completed a marathon. The for loop is to provide each of them a bottle of energy drink. But for the top 3 rankers we would also provide one chocolate! Now just think this collection as an ArrayList. We could do lot other complex steps in the loop. But parallaly could we just identify, what was the sequence number when it was added? Thanks...

Comment: @user1027056 - but in that example, wouldn't you have an object type with their finish time as well, and you could order by that? It isn't clear where the data you're putting into the table type is coming from (another table? then why hold it in a collection?), or why you need to use it in SQL - rather than looping over an associative array as a purely PL/SQL activity.

Comment: :) Yes sure.. I told even in the question that the sequence scenario can be implemented using other data structure. leave it. My basic curiosity is towards the index. As we can insert data into a collection index by index at our will, I just want to know if there is any way to get back those indexes inside an sql query. May be my example is not fitting enough, but my curiosity is purly technical; towards the features of PL-Sql. :)

Comment: @user1027056 - yes, I said you already seemed to know you could use object types. `ROWNUM` is the only alternative I can think of, and it's isn't really safe. There is no index in an SQL type, only in (some) PL/SQL types. If you're using an SQL type in a query you can't use PL/SQL aspects. When you populate `v_Data` the order you define the values isn't necessarily preserved anywhere at all; Oracle may happen to keep them in that order in memory and retrieve them in that order, but not necessarily.

Answer (score 0):

If indexing is important, use Associative Arrays(Also known as Index-by tables)

Refer [his](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96624/05_colls.htm#34607).

Comment: But could that be used in an sql query; as in the example I have casted it into table?